# JSON object to a rails object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

I create a JSON object in my html view using JSON.stringify(object) which outputs the following JSON object

```
{
 "0X1W6": "{\"type\":\"Hourly\",\"hr\":\"12\",\"min\":\"30\",\"every_hr\":\"5\"}",
  "Tk18f": "{\"type\":\"Daily\",\"hr\":\"12\",\"min\":\"30\",\"days_checked\":[1,4]}"
}
```

How do I convert this to a ruby object which would look something like this:

```
[
  { :type => 'Hourly', :hr => 12, :min => 30, :every_hr => 5}
  { :type => 'Daily', :hr => 12, :min => 30, :days_checked => [1,4]}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = []

z = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode( '{
  "0X1W6": "{\"type\":\"Hourly\",\"hr\":\"12\",\"min\":\"30\",\"every_hr\":\"5\"}",
  "Tk18f": "{\"type\":\"Daily\",\"hr\":\"12\",\"min\":\"30\",\"days_checked\":[1,4]}"
}')

z.each_value do|i|
  x = {}
  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(i).each{|k,v|
    x[k.to_sym] = (v.class == String && v.to_i.to_s == v) ? v.to_i : v
  }
  result << x
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
 "0X1W6": "{\"type\":\"Hourly\",\"hr\":\"12\",\"min\":\"30\",\"every_hr\":\"5\"}",
  "Tk18f": "{\"type\":\"Daily\",\"hr\":\"12\",\"min\":\"30\",\"days_checked\":[1,4]}"
}.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are passing that JSON from JavaScript to your server. On the server, you can use the 'json' gem to parse JSON like so: `o = JSON.parse json_string`.

If you literally need the data structure combined (removing the keys 0X1W6 and Tk18f), you'll have to post-process your ruby hash into an array. Using the same technique, you can convert string keys into symbols.

Comment: JSON.parse json_string is parsing it to { 0X1W6 => "{ type : Hourly....} so the second hash is getting stored as string instead of a hash

Answer (score 0):

When I understand correctly, you HAVE JSON and want a ruby hash. Within rails this can be done with ActiveSupport::Json.decode(json) while 'json' is a string. But this would not give you the exact results you are looking for, you would furthermore have to do:

```
ActiveSupport::Json.decode(json).values.symbolize_keys
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `symbolize_keys'

Comment: I assumed you were using rails which provides this method on Hash through activesupport. Without rails, you can either require this part of activesupport or symbolize the keys yourself like shown in Sector's post.